# Creating boot script for webcam

Tags: raspbian, linux

I seem to be having trouble getting this to work, I'm trying to run mjpg-streamer when the Raspberry boots, but it doesn't using the script below. I have mjpg-streamer installed in: /home/pi/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer

I appreciate any help provided! Thank you.

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh

STREAMER=/home/pi/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer/mjpg_streamer
DEVICE=/dev/video0
RESOLUTION=320x240
FRAMERATE=25
HTTP_PORT=8080

$STREAMER -i "./input_uvc.so -n -d $DEVICE -r $RESOLUTION -f $FRAMERATE" -o "./output_http.so -n -p $HTTP_PORT"
```

Comment: does this script work when run manually? how did you make this script to run at boot time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it after trial and error:

```
#!/bin/sh

STREAMER=/home/pi/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer/mjpg_streamer
DEVICE=/dev/video0
RESOLUTION=320x240
FRAMERATE=25
HTTP_PORT=8080

$STREAMER -i "/home/pi/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer/input_uvc.so -n -d $DEVICE -r 
$RESOLUTION -f $FRAMERATE" -o "/home/pi/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer/output_http.so -n -p 
$HTTP_PORT"
```

Comment: does this script work with the raspberry camera module?

Comment: @troop231: How you actually make it so start from boot ? Can you specify what command you've used ?

Answer (score 1):

What I've used and it works for me is:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# created by : meinside@gmail.com
#
# last update: 2014.01.24.
#

################
# customize these:

# mjpg_streamer's install location
MJPG_STREAMER_INSTALL="/home/pi/builds/mjpg-streamer"

# mjpg_streamer excutable's location
MJPG_STREAMER="$MJPG_STREAMER_INSTALL/mjpg_streamer"

# streaming port
MJPG_STREAMER_PORT="8080"

# htmls and related files' location
MJPG_STREAMER_WWW="$MJPG_STREAMER_INSTALL/www"

# video device
DEVICE_IN="/dev/video0"

# video settings
RESOLUTION="640x480"
FPS=24

# authentication
USERNAME="pi"
PASSWORD="raspberry"
if [ ! -z $USERNAME ] && [ ! -z $PASSWORD ]; then
    AUTH="-c $USERNAME:$PASSWORD"
else
    AUTH=""
fi

# LED blink
LED="off"   # on/off/blink/auto (may not work on rpi camera modules)

# plugin
PLUGIN_IN="$MJPG_STREAMER_INSTALL/input_uvc.so -d $DEVICE_IN -r $RESOLUTION -f $FPS -l $LED"
PLUGIN_OUT="$MJPG_STREAMER_INSTALL/output_http.so -p $MJPG_STREAMER_PORT -w $MJPG_STREAMER_WWW $AUTH"



################
# run mjpg_streamer
$MJPG_STREAMER -i "$PLUGIN_IN" -o "$PLUGIN_OUT"
################
```

**[Follow along these steps in order to make it work](https://github.com/meinside/rpi-mjpg-streamer)**

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding this to `rc.local`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you most definitely should replace `./input_uvc.so` in your script with the full-path links, because most probably it's not going to be started from your home directory or whatever place you think it might be started from.